# BMW E60 530i - Dashboard LCD Issues

Tags: bmw, dashboard

After parking my car for too long I decided to drive it. I noticed that the dashboard LCD is covered in red.  I don't know how this occurred.

[image]

Is there a possible fix for this?

Is there a replacement LCD?

Do I even need to replace it?

Comment: I'm curious as to the in car temperature and whether the car was sitting in direct sunlight when this happened. I've seen this happen on LCD panels that sit in the sun for too long though they eventually go back to normal.

Comment: its was parked under the sun for too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in my old E39 M5, in that case it was possible to ignore the problem since the display was only informational.  The biggest thing that concerns me with your failure is that you will not be able to check the oil level since if I remember correctly there is no dipstick on that car.  Other issues I can think of would be not being able to reset the service interval for the various systems.

There is not a replacement display available by itself, you will need to replace the whole cluster which is running $800-900 from BMW and I found one for $200 on ebay.  I am guessing the part number is 62109194887 you should validate that based on the specifics on your car.